# Getting info from MTP device: "friendly name" is always empty

Tags: c#, mtp

I am using this project to fetch data via MTP:

https://github.com/notpod/wpd-lib

My problem: the "friendly name" of the device is always empty. Windows shows a friendly name under "This PC", so it should be feasible.

This is how the mentioned github project tries to retrieve the friendly name (from the file [WindowsPortableDevice.cs](https://github.com/notpod/wpd-lib/blob/master/wpd-lib/WindowsPortableDevice.cs)):

```
var WPD_DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME = new PortableDeviceApiLib._tagpropertykey();
WPD_DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME.fmtid = new Guid(0x26D4979A, 0xE643, 0x4626, 0x9E, 0x2B, 0x73, 0x6D, 0xC0, 0xC9, 0x2F, 0xDC);
WPD_DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME.pid = 12;

string friendlyName;            
propertyValues.GetStringValue(ref DevicePropertyKeys.WPD_DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME, out friendlyName);
```

As stated before, the result of `friendlyName` is always empty.

---

**What I have tried so far:**

In [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpdblog/2007/11/26/creating-a-temperature-sensor-gadget-for-windows-sidebar-with-c-2/) I found this other possible solution, which uses the `PortableDeviceManagerClass` instead of the `PortableDeviceClass`:

```
string RetrieveFriendlyName(
                        PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass PortableDeviceManager,
                        string PnPDeviceID)
{
    uint   cFriendlyName = 0;
    ushort[] usFriendlyName;
    string strFriendlyName = String.Empty;

    // First, pass NULL as the LPWSTR return string parameter to get the total number
    // of characters to allocate for the string value.
    PortableDeviceManager.GetDeviceFriendlyName(PnPDeviceID, null, ref cFriendlyName);

    // Second allocate the number of characters needed and retrieve the string value.

    usFriendlyName = new ushort[cFriendlyName];
    if (usFriendlyName.Length > 0)
    {
        PortableDeviceManager.GetDeviceFriendlyName(PnPDeviceID, usFriendlyName, ref cFriendlyName);

        // We need to convert the array of ushorts to a string, one
        // character at a time.
        foreach (ushort letter in usFriendlyName)
            if (letter != 0)
                strFriendlyName += (char)letter;

        // Return the friendly name
        return strFriendlyName;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

The problem here is that I seem to have a different signature of `GetDeviceFriendlyName` (different `Interop.PortableDeviceApiLib.dll`?). This is mine:

```
void GetDeviceFriendlyName(string pszPnPDeviceID, ref ushort pDeviceFriendlyName, ref uint pcchDeviceFriendlyName);
```

It does not accept `null` or `ushort[]`.

I tested the following, just to see how it behaved:

```
var pDeviceFriendlyName = default(ushort);
var pcchDeviceFriendlyName = default(uint);
GetDeviceFriendlyName(pszPnPDeviceID, ref pDeviceFriendlyName, ref pcchDeviceFriendlyName);
```

...but it threw an exception: `"The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Windows does not use "friendly name" to show the device on "This PC", but "device model" instead:

```
WPD_DEVICE_MODEL.fmtid = new Guid(0x26D4979A, 0xE643, 0x4626, 0x9E, 0x2B, 0x73, 0x6D, 0xC0, 0xC9, 0x2F, 0xDC);
WPD_DEVICE_MODEL.pid = 8;
```